# SQL request - Display Dates with entry between two dates

Tags: c#, sql, database, date

i want to get back all dates that are between start and end as well as start and end itself. For some reason the result only displays the dates between start and end and end but not start.

I tried to switch around the bigger then, smaller then and is equal symbols as i could not explain where else the mistake should be

this is the events code:

```
private void monthCalendar1_DateSelected(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
        {
            string language = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name;

            if (!(language == "de-DE"))
            {
                if (language == "es-ES")
                {
                }
                else if (language == "en-GB")
                {
                    DateTime start = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart;
                    DateTime end = monthCalendar1.SelectionEnd;

                    MySqlConnection conn = DBUtils.GetDBConnection();
                    conn.Open();

                    MySqlDataAdapter adapterid;
                    DataTable dtschichten = new DataTable();

                    MySqlCommand feedid = conn.CreateCommand();
                    feedid.CommandText = "SELECT id, datum, atotal, ptotal, total FROM arbeitszeiten WHERE fullname = '" + comboBox1.Text + "' and active = 'NEIN' and datum >= '" + start + "' and datum <= '" + end + "'";
                    adapterid = new MySqlDataAdapter(feedid);
                    adapterid.Fill(dtschichten);

                    dtschichten.Columns["id"].ColumnName = "ID";
                    dtschichten.Columns["datum"].ColumnName = "Shiftdate";
                    dtschichten.Columns["atotal"].ColumnName = "Worktime";
                    dtschichten.Columns["ptotal"].ColumnName = "Breaktime";
                    dtschichten.Columns["total"].ColumnName = "Total time";
                    BindingSource bSourceschichten = new BindingSource();

                    bSourceschichten.DataSource = dtschichten;
                    dataGridView.DataSource = bSourceschichten;
                    adapterid.Update(dtschichten);

                    DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView.Columns[0];
                    column.Width = 30;

                    conn.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Your language setting is currently not supported" + "\n" + "Please change your primary language setting for Windows" + "\n" + "\n" + "The Programm will shut down now !", "Critial Failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                DateTime start = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart;
                DateTime end = monthCalendar1.SelectionEnd;

                MySqlConnection conn = DBUtils.GetDBConnection();
                conn.Open();

                MySqlDataAdapter adapterid;
                DataTable dtschichten = new DataTable();

                MySqlCommand feedid = conn.CreateCommand();
                feedid.CommandText = "SELECT id, datum, atotal, ptotal, total FROM arbeitszeiten WHERE fullname = '" + comboBox1.Text + "' and active = 'NEIN' and datum >= '" + start + "' and datum <= '" + end + "'";
                adapterid = new MySqlDataAdapter(feedid);
                adapterid.Fill(dtschichten);

                dtschichten.Columns["id"].ColumnName = "ID";
                dtschichten.Columns["datum"].ColumnName = "Schichtdatum";
                dtschichten.Columns["atotal"].ColumnName = "Arbeitszeit";
                dtschichten.Columns["ptotal"].ColumnName = "Pausenzeit";
                dtschichten.Columns["total"].ColumnName = "Zeit gesammt";
                BindingSource bSourceschichten = new BindingSource();

                bSourceschichten.DataSource = dtschichten;
                dataGridView.DataSource = bSourceschichten;
                adapterid.Update(dtschichten);

                DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView.Columns[0];
                column.Width = 30;

                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "displays the dates between start and end and end but not start."?

Comment: Please read on SQL Parameters. Your code is prone to an SQL Injection attack.

Comment: i want the results to show up in a data grid view. if i for example choose 22.07 as start and 25.07 as end i get displayed 23.07, 24, 25 but not the 22.07 entry

Comment: "Your code is prone to an SQL Injection attack." oookay.. whats the problem with it ?

Comment: is there entry in your table which has 22.07?

Comment: Pass on SQL parameters with the SQL code `WHERE datum BETWEEN @start AND @end`, setting @start to the value `start.AddDays(1)`

Comment: "is there entry in your table which has 22.07?" yes ^^

Comment: ``Use DateTime.TryParse() or DateTime.TryParseExact(), convert it to a DateTime variable, do a .AddDays(1), pass it on as an SQL parameter with the SQL code WHERE datum BETWEEN @start AND @end.

i could use som moe infos according to that.. dont realy get what you mean

Comment: @SvenRademacher Is your sql query works fine in mysql? not inside c# code

Comment: @James, it should, yes (just the request part it self of cause)

Comment: @SvenRademacher if it works in MySQL then don't tag MYSQL since it isn't sql issue.

Comment: @James well i save my data in a mysql and the request gos the mysql database so it made sence for me :-) (removed it if that satifies you ^^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQL parameters to avoid SQL injection and use BETWEEN for neatness' sake.

```
MySqlCommand feedid = conn.CreateCommand();
feedid.CommandText = "SELECT id, datum, atotal, ptotal, total FROM arbeitszeiten WHERE fullname = @fullname and active = 'NEIN' and datum BETWEEN @start AND @end";
feedid.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullname", comboBox1.Text);
feedid.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", start.AddDays(1));
feedid.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", end);
```

Comment: ["AddWithValue is Evil"](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) ;)

Comment: otherwise everyone could just send the request he wnt instead of the predifined one ?

Comment: feedid.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", start.AddDays(1)); wouldnt this make the 22.07 the 23.07 ?

Comment: kk, you where right just had to make it -1 day instead of 1

Comment: ps.: the parameters seem to make the respond slower, is it just me or is that true ?

Comment: @SvenRademacher I doubt you would notice anything different. Could be other conditions.

Comment: @stickybit interesting bit. Does the same hold for MySQL (which is the case here)?

Comment: Guessing the right type and therefore representation is a client side problem, so I'd say yes, it affects virtually all DBMS.

Comment: @stickybit That's what I thought as well, but I was curious as to why the article was specifically referring to SQL Server.